# What plans do we have for Mass Effect 3?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Given our recent contests, and that Mass Effect 3 is probably [in the sweet spot](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/whats-the-next-big-thing-for-gaming-se) for this site, it seems a given that we should do something in conjunction with its launch.  If we're going to have a promotion with some significant prizes, and we could announce it in time to get some of the Mass Effect 3 fan sites to post about it, that would be huge in terms of increasing visibility going into the launch.  Do people have sites they think we could get to post contest info, or ideas about promotions we could do?

Comment: I hope there will be a promotion of some kind, this is a game I can't wait to get my hands on

Comment: Promoting our contest on our G+/Facebook pages is a must. I just posted a promotion for our current contest, and we'll do the same for any future ones.

Comment: Indeed, this may be so. Stack is always finding ways to help the community and grow the site, fear not. Completely unrelated and not correlated with anything (with or without sarcasm?), if people have contacts at other sites, ping me or send me an email.

Answer (score 11):

SE is planning an epic promo around the Mass Effect 3 release.

You will know when it's on. You will know...

When it goes public, I'd encourage anyone interested to post about it on their personal sites, blogs and friends' sites. But until then, shhhhh, it's seekrit.

That's all I can say at the moment.